# Disable Windows Auto Update Using Java

Tags: java, swing, process, controlpanel

```
try {
    final String REG_ADD_CMD ="cmd /c reg add \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\"+
                              "Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate"+
                              "\\Auto Update\" /v AUOptions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f";
    Process objProcess;
    //objProcess cmd /c = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] 
    //{"REG ADD \"", " HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows
    //\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate\\Auto Update"," /v AUOptions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f"});

    objProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(REG_ADD_CMD);
    System.out.println("REG_ADD_CMD:::"+REG_ADD_CMD);
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(objProcess.getInputStream()));
    String line=reader.readLine();
    System.out.println("Windows auto update::::"+line);
    final int exitStatus = objProcess.waitFor();
    int exitVal = objProcess.exitValue();
    System.out.println("exitStatus::::"+exitStatus);
    System.out.println("exitVal::::"+exitVal);
    //System.out.println("Processed finished with status: " + exitVal);

    if(exitStatus != 0){
        System.err.println("Error while installing application!!");
    }
        //objProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\"+
//                          "Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update" /v AUOptions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f");
}
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my code to diable a windows auto update in windows 7. Once i executed am getting responce as "The operation completed successfully" in my console, But its not reflecting in control panel
can some one help regarding this.
Thanks

Comment: Oh my what a long title!

Comment: To disable a windows auto update in windows 7 using java

Comment: ^ Now that's a more interesting title :)

Comment: do i need to add something in code to reflect the changes in control panel.command is working properly when am executing in cmd prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are on a wrong way. Indeed windows stores a lot of configuration information in registry. It does not mean however that component that stores this information and reads it on startup performs polling on registry value to see whether somebody else has changed the value.

This is what happens in your case. There is a component that is responsible on automatic updates. It starts when system starts and reads its configuration from registry. Then you change the registry value but this component does not know anything about this.

To perform this operation correctly you should find API that does it and call it. Fortunately somebody already implemented command line utility that does this task: http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2012/10/manage-automatic-updates-from-the-command-line/

Take a look on this article. Run the utility from java and hopefully it will work for you. I am sure that there are other solutions that do something similar. For example take a look on WMI. If you find WMI API that does it you can write JScript or VBScript and then run it from java using `cscript` interpreter.

Comment: please tell how to run the utility from java?

Comment: You can run it exactly as you run any other utility using either `System.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using ProcessBuilder, or at least the `Runtime.exec` that takes a `String[]` rather than a single string, as the single-string exec almost certainly doesn't split up words the way you want it to.

```
Process objProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
   "cmd", "/c", "reg", "add",
   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate\\Auto Update",
    "/v", "AUOptions", "/t", "REG_DWORD",
    "/d", "1", "/f"
});
```

You don't need to  add additional quotes round the arguments that contain spaces.

Comment: I think that the problem is likely to be caching of registry values.  Invoking the "reg" command more elegantly won't solve that.

Comment: I tried above code.Am getting "The operation completed successfully" in console.but its not reflecting in control panel.please suggest a way to get in control panel